# Pod on EKS cluster cannot reach maria db (RDS) within the same VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to connect to my rds instance using a pod on an eks cluster but I'm having trouble. I have a VPC on AWS that has 4 subnets (2 pub, 2 private). Within this VPC I have 1 eks instance and 1 Maria db instance - both of which share the same vpc and subnets.

The eks cluster has:

1. a service CIDR of 10.100.0.0/16
2. the secgroup for the eks cluster has inbound rules for all traffic with outbound rules for all traffic for the IP range of 10.0.0.0/20.

The Maria db instance has a secgroup with inbound rules:

1. accept all traffic from IP range 10.0.0.0/24
2. accept all TCP MYSQL/Aurora traffic at port 3306 from IP range 10.0.0.0/24

When I use the pod on the eks cluster to attempt to connect I get a timeout which hints at connectivity issues. When I use the reachability analyzer it states that the instances cannot reach each other. Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The eks cluster has:
>
> a service CIDR of 10.100.0.0/16
>
> the secgroup for the eks cluster has inbound rules for all traffic with outbound rules for all traffic for the IP range of 10.0.0.0/20.

So the EKS cluster has 65,536 possible IP addresses. And it is allowed to send outbound traffic to 4,096 possible IP addresses within the VPC.

> The Maria db instance has a secgroup with inbound rules:
>
> accept all traffic from IP range 10.0.0.0/24
>
> accept all TCP MYSQL/Aurora traffic at port 3306 from IP range 10.0.0.0/24

So the Database only accepts incoming traffic from 256 possible IP addresses within the VPC, a tiny subset of the 65,536 possible addresses the EKS cluster may be using. You would need to change that to match the CIDR block being used by the EKS cluster.

Your security group rules are only allowing a small subset of all your VPC IP addresses for some reason.

I suggest you stop using CIDR blocks for your security group rules all together. Change the EKS cluster's outbound rule to allow traffic to the database server's security group ID, and change the database server's inbound rule to allow traffic from the EKS cluster's security group ID.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will do that going forward.

Comment: I hate to ping you again but changing that CIDR blocks to 10.0.0.0/16 didn't help. I'm looking for a how to add secgroups to outbound rules but can't find anything. Can you help with this?

Comment: Are you assigning security groups to the pods, or just to the EKS instance? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/security-groups-for-pods.html

Comment: I made a secgroup for the eks instance. Thanks for the docs I ended up figuring out how to add the secgroups to traffic rules! Big help.